# Sql servers are using Kerberros and NTLM Authentication

Tags: sql-server, security, performance, authentication, performance-tuning

Lately I have been facing failed connection errors mainly due to servers using NTLM Authentication. In our environment the servers have a combination of ntlm and kerberoos. My question is If i ask my Domain admin to manually register all the service accounts to use the kerberoos instead of ntlm authentication will there be any problem or any performance issues that might arise ?

Comment: You shoud allow the accounts the ability to register the SPNs themselves, it greatly reduces the headaches involved. Grant ReadServicePrincipalName, WriteServicePrincipalName permissions to SELF on the accounts in AD.

Comment: Since it was not registered automatically i will need to have my domain admin manually register those, but again just wanted to know will there be any performance issue if the authentication mode is changed from ntlm to kerberoos on a production database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kerberos authentication should be faster and it is definitely more secure, so if you are at all concerned about security it should be enabled.  The only issue that I can think of that might occur is if the Service Principal Names (SPNs) incorrect, then logins will fail.  Accordingly, if you are adding SPNs to get it set up, I would recommend having the SETSPN commands ready so you can quickly will back out the changes that were made.

1. Add new SPNs
2. Test client / application connections (restart applications that connect to force new logins)
3. Remove SPNs if tests fail and investigate

Ref: [What Is Kerberos Authentication?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780469(v=ws.10).aspx#w2k3tr_kerb_what_pckk)

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I guess it wont be wise to take the risk if it involves login failures, but I will have my network admin look into the accounts the sql services are using

Comment: Another option is to give the SQL Server service account the permission to modify it's own SPNs.  This will ensure that the correct SPNs get created the next time the SQL Server service starts.  http://www.sqlmastersconsulting.com.au/SQL-Server-Blog/granting-a-sql-service-account-permissions-to-create-spns